# Haskell; Libglade-Warning: could not find glade file

Tags: haskell, glade

Following http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Gtk2Hs/Windows#Windows_7_32_bit I installed `Gtk2Hs / Glade` and everthing went well.

Now at `C:\Users\X\Desktop\test` I have the following files: `gui.hs, hellogtk2hs.glade`,
where `gui.hs` contains the lines of the example shown on http://projects.haskell.org/gtk2hs/docs/tutorial/glade/ (lines 1-21)
and `hellogtk2hs.glade` is the xml-file which is created following the tutorial.
Compiling and making a .exe file works, but if I run the the .exe file this error occurs:

> (gui.exe:16924): libglade-WARNING **: could not find glade file 'hellogtk2hs.glade'
>   gui.exe: user error (Pattern match failure in do expression at gui.hs:8:5-12)

where Line 8 is: `Just xml    <- xmlNew "hellogtk2hs.glade"`

As far as I see there is no typo and both the .exe and .glade are in the same folder - can anyone help me? Why can the `.glade` file not be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start your executable from the same directory as the glade file is in. It depends on how you invoke the executable; especially when you are using a terminal, or when you double click the executable file in Explorer, different working directories will be set.

To make sure that you always get to the glade file independent of the working directory, you should use an absolute path (`xmlNew "C:\Users\X\Desktop\test\hellogtk2hs.glade"`). You can use [Cabal's data file support](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2008/02/adding-data-files-using-cabal.html) to make this process easier when you want to make your project location-independent.

Comment: Thank you, now the .glade file is found. However now I get these errors (one of them still has to do with line 8):

libglade-WARNING **: Expected <glade-interface>.  Got <interface>.
libglade-WARNING **: did not finish in PARSER_FINISH state
gui.exe: user error (Pattern match failure in do expression at gui.hs:8:5-12). This is the .glade file: http://hpaste.org/64489

Comment: You might be using Glade for GTK3. You should either use Glade for GTK2, or change your .glade file manually, by for example replacing the `<interface>` tag with `<glade-interface>`. **EDIT:** You might be using Glade for GTK2 while you actually need GTK3. You'll have to experiment.